# Drupal Fivestar module not appearing in views

Tags: drupal, drupal-fivestar

I have installed drupal fivestar module. The module is working fine on the node page but when I go to views It doesnt give me any option to add Fivestar rating field. According to drupal and lullabot.com and other tutorial I have seen on the net I think the field has to be there but I am not sure why it is not apearing at my view page. I have clean url enabled. Voting api installed and enabled. Fivestar rating's all 3 modules are installed and enabled. I have also tried to run update.php as I thought may be it is a cache issue but no luck. Can anyone help me debugging this issue or alteast tell me anyother way to add rating on my views.It will be highly apreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a video where they explain how to do it. http://www.channels.com/episodes/show/6336042/Building-Views-with-Fivestar-and-VotingAPI

First you must create a Relationship in your View

Comment: Thankyou so much corbacho this video solve my problem. Yes relation must be needed I was missing that part